# cakephp with external View files

Tags: cakephp

I am required to employ [webEdition](http://www.webedition.org/) as the CMS for a web presence, which shall contain a form realised with CakePHP.

Unfortunately, both systems employ directory structures, which are incompatible with each other: CakePHP requires an "app"-folder with several subfolders, "Model", "View", "Controller", whereas webEdition provides (php) template files, from which the frontend (html) files are generated via a http-backend that must stay functional (as it is the point of using webEdition in the first place).

As such, while I can put the model and controller files into their respective CakePHP-folders, I need to write the view code into the webEdition templates. CakePHP [offers configuration files](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/installation/advanced-installation.html#sharing-cakephp-libraries-with-multiple-applications) to move its whole "app"-folder into arbitrary places, but this is arguably not what I require.

To summarise, the situation looks as follows:

- webEdition needs the templates to go to [webroot]/webedition/we/templates/[file].php
- CakePHP needs the View files to go to [arbitrary]/app/View/[controller name]/[file].[extension]
- the View code must go into the template
- references to the View code must reference the published files [webroot]/[file].html

Obviously these requirements are incompatible. Mayhap my understanding is wrong to begin with, but even if not, there should (hopefully) exist an alternate way to realise this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The requirements are obviously incompatible but there are several ways to work around that:

- Make the CakePHP form using AJAX or an iframe to call the CakePHP app directly
- Let webEdition deal with the form completely on it's own but write to the DB table the Cake app is using
- Have a RESTful API you cann call from the webEdition page and POST the data to the CakePHP app.

Comment: Ugh. Hardly ideal but doable, I guess.

Thank you.

Comment: I think you could go the RESTful way, it is easy to set up in Cake and you can do the whole HTTP POST via JS. So in the CMS you'll just need a form template and some JS. I don't think that's to hard to do. Maybe ~1h of work?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that via this setting in the app/Config/bootstrap.php file, the webroot folder may be specified as View folder - which is arguably more of a hack, but should allow to write cakePHP view code directly into a webEdition template, from where it would be carried through to the published file.

```
/**
 * The settings below can be used to set additional paths to models, views and controllers.
 *
 * App::build(array(
 *     'Model'                     => array('/path/to/models/', '/next/path/to/models/'),
 *     'Model/Behavior'            => array('/path/to/behaviors/', '/next/path/to/behaviors/'),
 *     'Model/Datasource'          => array('/path/to/datasources/', '/next/path/to/datasources/'),
 *     'Model/Datasource/Database' => array('/path/to/databases/', '/next/path/to/database/'),
 *     'Model/Datasource/Session'  => array('/path/to/sessions/', '/next/path/to/sessions/'),
 *     'Controller'                => array('/path/to/controllers/', '/next/path/to/controllers/'),
 *     'Controller/Component'      => array('/path/to/components/', '/next/path/to/components/'),
 *     'Controller/Component/Auth' => array('/path/to/auths/', '/next/path/to/auths/'),
 *     'Controller/Component/Acl'  => array('/path/to/acls/', '/next/path/to/acls/'),
 *     'View'                      => array('/path/to/views/', '/next/path/to/views/'),
 *     'View/Helper'               => array('/path/to/helpers/', '/next/path/to/helpers/'),
 *     'Console'                   => array('/path/to/consoles/', '/next/path/to/consoles/'),
 *     'Console/Command'           => array('/path/to/commands/', '/next/path/to/commands/'),
 *     'Console/Command/Task'      => array('/path/to/tasks/', '/next/path/to/tasks/'),
 *     'Lib'                       => array('/path/to/libs/', '/next/path/to/libs/'),
 *     'Locale'                    => array('/path/to/locales/', '/next/path/to/locales/'),
 *     'Vendor'                    => array('/path/to/vendors/', '/next/path/to/vendors/'),
 *     'Plugin'                    => array('/path/to/plugins/', '/next/path/to/plugins/'),
 * ));
 *
 */
```

... Not yet tested though and obviously not fit for a production system.